# Yocto (Intel IoT Image), installing packages

Tags: yocto, intel-galileo

Good day.

In debian I can to run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv python-serial python-pyparsing python-numpy python-wxgtk2.8
```

How to do it on yocto (Intel IoT Image)?

1) build from source it all with building from source all dependencies?

2) is a good solution - install apt-get on yocto?

3) Maybe, I can to use opkg for installing it, (but in "opkg list" I can't see, for example, python-wxgtk2.8 ), where can I find good repository, default repository is very poor?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can install packages using opkg. You can use the [repos](http://iotdk.intel.com/). Refer this excellent blog from Alex on [package configuration](http://alextgalileo.altervista.org/package-repo-configuration-instructions.html).